# Unexpected token '<' in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I downloaded a project from codesandbox. Its folder structure and index file looks as following:

[image]

**index.js file:**

```
const { StrictMode } = require("react");
const ReactDOM=require("react-dom") ;

const App = require("./App")

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

after running npm intall, package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "quill-forms-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "How to create typeform clone easily with React",
  "keywords": [],
  
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@quillforms/react-renderer-utils": "1.0.25",
    "@quillforms/renderer-core": "1.5.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I tried running with node index.js inside src folder in VSC. but I will get the following error in line 8 of the **index.js** as following:

```
C:\Users\Shafigh\Downloads\quill-forms-example-forked\src\index.js:8
  <StrictMode>
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

any hint, what changes should i make to the code?

Comment: How did you execute it in VSC?

Comment: what is your react version?

Comment: qrsngky : cd src and then node index.js

Comment: what is your App.js code?

Comment: @ss node cannot execute jsx directly (`<Tag></Tag>` will just give you a syntax error if you try). You need a transformation before that. You do have the `"build"` script like `npm run build` set up, but somehow `"start": ` is missing? It should be `"react-scripts start"` if it was created by create-react-app. Try inputting `react-scripts start` into the console and see what the output is like.

Answer (score 1):

First run `npm install` in the terminal of root folder (not src folder) which will take a while since it will install all the packages in package.json.
Then run `npm run dev` which will start it in a browser most possibly in [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000). Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: I ran npm install as you said , but npm run dev didnt work, as ther is no script for dev

Comment: npm start should do it

Answer (score 0):

Remove `StrictMode`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <App />
);
```